# $-ia(1\pm \sqrt{1-1/a^2})$, $a>0$ inside unit circle?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given $a>0$ I would like to know whether:
$\alpha=-ia(1+ \sqrt{1-1/a^2})$ and
$\beta =-ia(1- \sqrt{1-1/a^2})$ are inside the unit circle.

How can I check that?

Comment: It simplifies to $-i(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$. It seems that no. You should show that $|a+\sqrt{a^2-1}|\leq 1$.

Comment: $\beta$ yes. $\alpha$ no

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra Can  you show me your method?

Comment: $\alpha=\beta$?

Comment: @user40615 That simplification is obvious, but it doesn't show anything...

Comment: @James: Daniel Fischer has shown the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\alpha\cdot\beta = (-i)^2a^2\left(1 - \sqrt{1-1/a^2}^2\right) = -a^2(1/a^2) = -1,$$

so either both lie on the unit circle, or one lies inside the unit disk and the other outside.

For $0 < a \leqslant 1$, the radicand $1-1/a^2$ is a non-positive real number, hence the square root purely imaginary, and then $\lvert\alpha\rvert = \lvert\beta\rvert = 1$.

For $a > 1$, the radicand $1-1/a^2$ is positive, and if you take the branch of the square root that is positive on the positive real axis, you have $\lvert\beta\rvert < \lvert\alpha\rvert$, and hence then $\beta$ lies inside the unit disk, $\alpha$ outside.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a coincidence that $\alpha\cdot \beta =-1$?

Comment: Most probably not. These are the zeros of $X^2 +2iaX -1$, and probably that's where the two expressions come from. The constant term of a (monic) quadratic is the product of its roots.